# Cannot assign "5809L": "PedidoComissao.artista" must be a "Cliente" instance

Tags: python, django, model

I have a model like below:

```
class PedidoComissao(models.Model):
    artista = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, verbose_name='Artista')
    pedido = models.ForeignKey(Pedido)
    pedidoitem = models.ForeignKey(PedidoItem, verbose_name='Arte')
    valor_receber = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
    data_pagamento = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    origem_venda = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name, verbose_name_plural = u'Comissão', u'Comissões'
```

When I try to insert data with a code like below:

```
comissao = PedidoComissao(artista = produto.artista_id,
                          pedido = pedido,
                          pedidoitem = item,
                          valor_receber = valor_receber,
                          origem_venda = origem_venda)
comissao.save()
```

I get an error like this:

```
Cannot assign "5809L": "PedidoComissao.artista" must be a "Cliente" instance.
```

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: just  change `artista = produto.artista_id` to `artista = produto.artista`

Comment: assuming produto has an artista field that is an actual Cliente instance ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
artista = produto.artista_id
```

should probably be

```
artista = Cliente.objects.get(produto.artista_id)
```

but its hard to tell exactly,since we dont know what `produto` is

the problem is your model expects an actual Cliente instance not just its id ...

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `PedidoComissao(artista=produto.artista_id, ...)`, but `artista` should be an instance of the model class, not the id. You can either do `PedidoComissao(artista_id=produto.artista_id, ...)` or `PedidoComissao(artista=produto.artista, ...)`